# Callback when interface rotation ENDED in iOS 9?

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios9, uiinterfaceorientation, transition

I haven’t seen a definitive answer to this question yet, lots of noise around the iOS 8 changes, but I’d like to address it for iOS 9:

**What is the correct way to get a callback after an interface orientation change ENDS?**

As of iOS 9, `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` has been deprecated, and the official documentation tells us to use `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator` instead. This gives us (through the `transitionCoordinator`) a means of animating alongside the transition, and a completion block, but no direct callback for the bona fide ‘end’ of the transition.

The other method from the `transitionCoordinator` is `notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock:`, but this appears to report the end of the interactive part of the transition, not the entire thing.

So, is the “official” way to do this to implement `animateAlongsideTransition:completion`, and simply ignore the animation option?

I realise we can still use good old `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`, but it’s always better to modernise where possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore animation option, just use 'nil' for it.

Example from WWDC 2014 'View Controller Advancements in iOS 8':

```
- (void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)s withTransitionCoordinator:(UIVCTC)t
{
    orientation = [self orientationFromTransform: [t targetTransform]];
    oldOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    [self myWillRotateToInterfaceOrientation:orientation duration:duration];

    [t animateAlongsideTransition:^(id <UIVCTCContext>) {
        [self myWillAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:orientation duration:duration];
    } 
    completion: ^(id <UIVCTCContext>) {
        [self myDidAnimateFromInterfaceOrientation:oldOrientation];
    }];
}
```

Works fine with iOS 9.